# fetching data from database and send as email attachment using php

Tags: php, mysql, email, csv

I want to send E-mail using php with an attachment(CSV file). it is working fine but i want to make that csv file from data of one of tables in my database.how can i do that??

```
<?php
    require_once('\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php');
    $email = new PHPMailer();
    $email->From = 'myid@yahoo.in';
    $email->FromName = 'name';
    $email->Subject = 'Message Subject';
    $email->Body = "GO away";
    $email->AddAddress( 'abc@example.com' );

    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, array('serial', 'group','end'));


    $rows = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM list');
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    mysqli_close($db);
    $file_to_attach = 'data.csv';
    $email->AddAttachment( $output , 'data.csv' );
    return $email->Send();
?>
```

Comment: in $output you must open / create a file like 'export.csv' which then can be attached like your "data.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');` line to `$output = fopen('data.csv', 'w');`.

That should create a data.csv file in the directory your PHPscript is located. It's important to have writing permissions for the script on that directory.

Answer (score 0):

**It works for me. I hope it will help you**

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');
if (!$con)
{
    die("error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$filename = "teaching_information";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM teaching_information order by id desc limit 0,10");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$filename2='datas/'.$filename.'.csv';
$fp = fopen($filename2, "w");
$seperator = "";
$comma = "";
foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $name);$comma = ",";}
$seperator .= "\n";
$seperator;
fputs($fp, $seperator);
mysqli_data_seek($sql, 0);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $seperator = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach ($row as $name => $value){$seperator .= $comma . '' . str_replace('', '""', $value);$comma = ",";}
    $seperator .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $seperator);
}

fclose($fp);

$my_file = $filename2;
$path = "datas/";
$from_name = "solomon";
$from_mail = "pss@gmail.com";
$mailto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$message = "Hi,\r\n do you got attachment?\r\n\r\Solomon";
$replyto = "pssworkcse@gmail.com";
$file = $my_file;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: " . $from_name . " <" . $from_mail . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $replyto . "\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename2 . "\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content . "\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--" . $uid . "--";
mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)

?>
```